# How do I set the App name when requesting Calender / Address Book access?

Tags: ios

I have an app in development that has some features for adding contact info to a users address book and adding events to their calendar. When the app makes the initial request for allowing access to the calendar or address book it pops up a message like this:

"" would like access to your Calendar

I cannot figure out how / where to set this string so that it displays the name of the App.

Comment: You might be looking for [CocoaKeys](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html) and specifically `NSCalendarsUsageDescription` for calendar privacy.

Comment: @AdilSoomro - no...that only sets the description underneath the actual title. My problem is that the title does not display the name of the app.

Comment: Have your properly set your app name in Build Settings > Product Name ?

Comment: Thanks, Adil. I found the issue since you got me poking around in the plist. I submitted an answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the following plist key is set to a proper value:

Bundle display name

Answer (score 0):

First check Product Name under Packaging. You can also set name like this -> select your target, "Info" tab, and set the "Bundle name" field to the name you want.